# Creating a WHILE Loop in Visio ShapeSheet

Tags: visio, shapesheet

*I'm aware that this can be easily done using VBA, but I'd like a macroless solution if possible.*

I have 2 User rows in a Shape's ShapeSheet: `User.Count` and `User.Loop`. `User.Count` will simply store a number, and the While loop will be performed by `User.Loop` using the following basic conditional:

```
User.Loop = IF(User.Count < 1000, SETF(GETREF(User.Count), User.Count + 1), "Loop complete!")  + DEPENDSON(User.Count)
```

This executes to `User.Count = 41` (these pulses of 41 are consistent). Is performing this type of loop possible?

Comment: `User.Count = 41` is limitation. We cant change it…

Comment: What an odd limitation. Thank you @Surrogate!

Comment: This limitation is designed to prevent circular reference! What purpose do you need the loop simulation for ?

Comment: @Surrogate I make interactive drawings for clients and wanted to do some basic  animations, so the WHILE loop would be incrementally expanding `Shape!Width` to "open" a menu.

Comment: 41 is the limit because if the answer ever becomes 42 then that is the end of Life, The Universe and Everything!

Comment: Have you tried changing the loop limit to 40 and the increment to 0.05 to give you 800 pulses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because if the answer ever becomes 42 then that is the end of Life, The Universe and Everything!

Paul you are right ! :)

> changing the loop limit to 40 and

Sad, but this trick dont works…

---

My experiment results.
[image]
[My example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUzEx8LQhqNqmtKkG-_dSsfltHrMQgtw/view?usp=sharing)
My loop can't make it to the 1000 mark. It has to stop at 80. You can continue the loop through the context menu `Go to 1000 limit`.